# Why is the y intercept of a G vs X curve treated as chemical potential?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Whenever I am to prove the fact that the $y$ intercept to the $G$ vs $X$ curve is basically my chemical potential, there are two equations that need to be assumed. One is 
$$G=\mu _{A}X_{A}+\mu _{B}X_{B},$$ 
and the other is the total differential expression of $\mathrm{d}G'$. However they are treated as two independent equations. However, are they not related? What is the  intuition to the geometrical interpretation of the chemical potential?

Comment: What have you done so far?  Are you familiar with the Gibbs Duhem equation?

Comment: I have done that but I really do not know the intuition behind the equation.

Comment: See Smith and van Ness, Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics, Chapter 11

Comment: Thanks @ChetMiller it was just what I was looking for.